# Generate a dictionary of all possible Kakuro solutions

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python and had an idea to try to generate a dictionary of all the possible solutions for a Kakuro puzzle. There are a few posts out there about these puzzles, but none that show how to generate said dictionary. What I'm after is a dictionary that has keys from 3-45, with their values being tuples of the integers which sum to the key (so for example mydict[6] = ([1,5],[2,4],[1,2,3])). It is essentially a Subset Sum Problem - https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html

I've had  a go at this myself and have it working for tuples up to three digits long. My method requires a loop for each additional integer in the tuple, so would require me to write some very repetitive code! Is there a better way to do this? I feel like i want to loop the creation of loops, if that is a thing?

```
def kakuro():
    L = [i for i in range(1,10)]
    mydict = {}
    for i in L:
        L1 = L[i:]
        for j in L1:
            if i+j in mydict:
                mydict[i+j].append((i,j))
            else:
                mydict[i+j] = [(i,j)]
            L2 = L[j:]
            for k in L2:
                if i+j+k in mydict:
                    mydict[i+j+k].append((i,j,k))
                else:
                    mydict[i+j+k] = [(i,j,k)]
    for i in sorted (mydict.keys()):
        print(i,mydict[i])
    return
```

my attempt round 2 - getting better!

```
def kakurodict():
    from itertools import combinations as combs 
    L = [i for i in range(1,10)]
    mydict={}
    mydict2={}
    for i in L[1:]:
        mydict[i] = list(combs(L,i))
        for j in combs(L,i):
            val = sum(j)
            if val in mydict2:
                mydict2[val].append(j)
            else:
                mydict2[val] = [j]    
    return mydict2
```

Comment: To clarify, an additional constraint is that the values within each tuple are unique, correct?

Comment: correct, we only want (1,2), not (1,2),(2,1) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is written with the following assumptions.

- dict[n] cannot have a list with the value [n].
- Each element in the subset has to be unique.

I hope there is a better solution offered by someone else, because when we generate all subsets for values 3-45, it takes quite some time. I believe the time complexity of the subset sum generation problem is 2^n so if n is 45, it's not ideal.

```
import itertools

def subsetsums(max):
    if (max < 45):
        numbers = [x for x in range(1, max)]
    else:
        numbers = [x for x in range(1, 45)]

    result = [list(seq) for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) == max]
    return(result)

mydict = {}
for i in range(3, 46):
    mydict[i] = subsetsums(i)

print(mydict)
```

Comment: Awesome, looks great! I did manage to have some success myself, also using itertools.combinations. I'll edit my question to show what I came up with. How does it compare time-wise to yours?

Comment: Based off some quick googling, I think your time complexity is better, but your memory management is off by quite a bit. For a solution of size 10 your code works for me. If I try to do 25, or 45, I get memory error. Whereas my solution is able to solve it in a reasonable time for 25.